# displaying the contents of a mysql query, only first field works

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using a mysqli prepard query with php, the code is:

```
$retreiveQuery = 'SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM USERS WHERE username = ?';

if ($getRecords = $con->prepare($retreiveQuery)) {
    $getRecords->bind_param("s", $username);

    $getRecords->execute();        
    $getRecords->bind_result($username, $firstname, $lastname);

echo "<h1>".$username."</h1>
<p><strong>First Name: </strong>".$firstname."
<p><strong>Surname: </strong>".$lastname."
} else {
print_r($con->error);
```

This is quite strange. username is the only field which is displayed. Why would the other columns not be being returned/bound?

If I do

```
SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM USERS WHERE username = 'test';
```

Directly to the database, all fields are displayed, and all contain valid data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call

```
$getRecords->fetch();
```

after `bind_result()`  to actually get the record.

Username was being output because you had already set it, to use as an input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use a different variable name for output of username? Like this:

SELECT username as user_name, firstname, lastname FROM USERS WHERE username = 'test';

and then

$getRecords->bind_result($user_name, $firstname, $lastname);

I wonder if it's getting confused by using the same name for both input and output?

Comment: ok..so it is a problem with result binding I guess..but how to tell what it is?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run this, but I notice that you are using the same variable, $username for both the bound param and bound result variable.

It may be that the result is not returning ANY of them, but $username has a value displayed because you are assigning it beforehand, not because it's coming from the database.

Try using different varaibles like $param_user and $result_user, and see what happens.  My guess is that none of the result will be returned, which will point to a problem with the query or the result binding.

Comment: yes, this is the answer. So what could be the problem with the result binding...how would I check this?